# play music in sdcard if exist file

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-music-player

i am playing music from SD-card and file exist it is playing music file but if it does not exist my app crashes what can i do?

```
package com.example.downloadplay;

public class AudioPlayer extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button playButton;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

playButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.ButtonPlayStop);
playButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File audioFile = new File(sdcard.getPath() + "/bluetooth/یه سوال دارم مگه.mp3");

 intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(audioFile), "audio/mp3");
 startActivity(intent);
 }
 }
```

Comment: Change your file title to english name and then it will work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if file exists with

```
if(audioFile.exists())
{
  intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(audioFile), "audio/mp3");
  startActivity(intent);
}
else
{
   // show error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether File exists or not by using [File.exists()](https://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29)

```
File f = new File(filePathString);
if(f.exists())
{ 
 //Play your sound
}
else
{
  //And your other stuffs goes here
}
```

> **Note** : `exists()` will return true for directories, too

Answer (score 0):

Use below code.

```
if(audioFile.exists())
{
  intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(audioFile), "audio/mp3");
  startActivity(intent);
}
else
{
   Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity_name.this);
                    alert.setTitle("Alert");
                    alert.setMessage("File does not exist");
                    alert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                    alert.show();
}
```